# Reverse the order of column based on other columns

Tags: perl

I am trying to manipulate a file which has around 1 million rows. Below is my example input:

```
chr1  GeneA  E1  -
chr1  GeneA  E2  -
chr1  GeneA  E3  -
chr1  GeneB  E1  +
chr1  GeneB  E2  +
chr1  GeneB  E3  +
chr1  GeneB  E4  +
chr1  GeneC  E1  -
chr1  GeneC  E2  -
chr2  GeneD  E1  +
```

I want to reverse the order of column 3 if the column 4 has "-" sign and the rows have same column 1 and 2 values. Example output:

```
chr1  GeneA  E1  -  E3
chr1  GeneA  E2  -  E2
chr1  GeneA  E3  -  E1
chr1  GeneB  E1  +  E1
chr1  GeneB  E2  +  E2
chr1  GeneB  E3  +  E3
chr1  GeneB  E4  +  E4
chr1  GeneC  E1  -  E2
chr1  GeneC  E2  -  E1
chr2  GeneD  E1  +  E1
```

I am trying to code the following steps:

1. Take first row and store in arrayA.
2. Take the second row.
3. If column 1 and 2 has same value as in previous row and column 5 has "-" sign, then push second row in arrayA else print the whole arrayA with reverse column 3.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open my $first, '<',$ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
my @previous=split(/\t/,<$first>);

while (<$first>) {
    my @current=split /\t/;
    if ($current[1] eq $previous[1] && $current[0] eq $previous[0] && $current[3] eq "-"){
        push @previous,[@current];
    }
    else{
        foreach (@previous) {
            print "$_","\t",reverse $previous[0][2];
        }
        @previous=@current;
    }
}
```

It is giving out the same as input file. Could you please help to make this code work?

Comment: Thanks. I think problem is with the push. The error is "Can't use string ("chr1  GeneA  E1  -
") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at rev_exon.pl line 18, <$first> line 2.

Comment: You need to reverse a column of a row of rows. You're storing that row of rows in `@previous` (except that you need to add `[]`s in the first and third assignment), but the way you're doing the reverse is wrong: you print the rows one by one, so you need to compute the reverse column and add the elements to *each* row before you start printing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY script.

To do this project, you just need to keep a buffer of lines to later process once you see a change in your first two fields.  This is a fairly common programming construct, especially when you're working with data that needs to be grouped and processed in some way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @buffer;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @data = split ' ';
    if (@buffer && ($data[0] ne $buffer[0][0] || $data[1] ne $buffer[0][1])) {
        process_buffer(@buffer);
        @buffer = ();
    }

    push @buffer, [@data, $_];
}

process_buffer(@buffer);

sub process_buffer {
    my @buffer = @_;
    my @col3 = map $_->[2], @buffer;
    @col3 = reverse @col3 if $buffer[0][3] eq '-';
    for my $i (0..$#buffer) {
        print $buffer[$i][-1], "  ", $col3[$i], "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
chr1  GeneA  E1  -
chr1  GeneA  E2  -
chr1  GeneA  E3  -
chr1  GeneB  E1  +
chr1  GeneB  E2  +
chr1  GeneB  E3  +
chr1  GeneB  E4  +
chr1  GeneC  E1  -
chr1  GeneC  E2  -
chr2  GeneD  E1  +
```

Outputs:

```
chr1  GeneA  E1  -  E3
chr1  GeneA  E2  -  E2
chr1  GeneA  E3  -  E1
chr1  GeneB  E1  +  E1
chr1  GeneB  E2  +  E2
chr1  GeneB  E3  +  E3
chr1  GeneB  E4  +  E4
chr1  GeneC  E1  -  E2
chr1  GeneC  E2  -  E1
chr2  GeneD  E1  +  E1
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working. Could you please add some comments in the code? e.g. how is this if statement working? and how about buffer? Just trying to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

I can't make proper sense of your description and code, but from your data example I think this is what you want.

Basically the third field in each row is copied to form a new fifth field. Then, in every sequence of rows where the first and second fields match and trhe fourth is a hyphen `-`, the row order of the new fifth columnn is reversed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile.txt';

my @block;
my $block_key;

while (<$fh>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  chomp;

  my @row = split /\t/;
  push @row, $row[2];
  my $key = join "\t", @row[0,1,3];

  if ($block_key and $block_key ne $key) {
    print_block(\@block);
    @block = ();
    $block_key = undef;
  }

  push @block, \@row;
  $block_key = $key;
  print_block(\@block) if eof;
}

close $fh;


sub print_block {
  my ($block) = @_;
  if ($block->[0][3] eq '-') {
    $block->[$_][4] = $block->[$#block - $_][4] for 0 .. $#block;
  }
  print join("\t", @$_), "\n" for @block;
}
```

**output**

```
chr1  GeneA E1  - E3
chr1  GeneA E2  - E2
chr1  GeneA E3  - E1
chr1  GeneB E1  + E1
chr1  GeneB E2  + E2
chr1  GeneB E3  + E3
chr1  GeneB E4  + E4
chr1  GeneC E1  - E2
chr1  GeneC E2  - E1
chr2  GeneD E1  + E1
```

---

**Update**

Here's another solution that doesn't use the subroutine. I'm not sure whether I prefer it, but you can make your own choice. The output is identical to that of the first program.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile.txt';

my @block;

while () {

  my $line = <$fh>;
  my @curr;
  if (defined $line) {
    chomp $line;
    @curr = split /\t/, $line;
    push @curr, $curr[2];
  }

  if (@block) {
    if (eof or $curr[0] eq $block[-1][0] and $curr[1] eq $block[-1][1]) {
      if ($block[0][3] eq '-') {
        $block[$_][4] = $block[$#block - $_][4] for 0 .. $#block;
      }
      print join("\t", @$_), "\n" for @block;
      @block = ();
    }
  }

  last if eof;

  push @block, \@curr;
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: +1 for decoding the code needed from the data output ... you "reverse engineered" a solution and did it without using `reverse()` (and without using a subroutine - I will +1 you again for that).  From the OP question I couldn't figure out which columns needed to be `reverse`-d.

Answer (score 1):

Create a buffer of lines with `-`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @buf;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @cols = split;
    if ($cols[3] eq '-') {
        push @buf, $_;
    }
    else {
        if (@buf) {
            my @lasts = reverse map { (split)[2] } @buf;
            my $i = 0;
            for my $line (@buf) {
                my @tokens = split /\s+/, $line;
                print join "\t", @tokens, $lasts[$i], "\n";
                $i++;
            }
            @buf = ();
        }
        print join "\t", @cols, $cols[2], "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
chr1  GeneA  E1  -
chr1  GeneA  E2  -
chr1  GeneA  E3  -
chr1  GeneB  E1  +
chr1  GeneB  E2  +
chr1  GeneB  E3  +
chr1  GeneB  E4  +
chr1  GeneC  E1  -
chr1  GeneC  E2  -
chr2  GeneD  E1  +
```